# Id value getting skipped on failed INSERT with spring data JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data JPA to persist data into PostgreSQL. I have an entity called 'Game' in which Id is primary key and it's auto generated value which gets incremented by '1'. I have another column 'game_code' which accepts only unique values.

Whenevr i tried to persist entity with gamecode value which is already exists in the table. it gives an error. which is corret. But, the value of the ID is getting skipped. Please find the below example.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
@Data
public class Game {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "GAME_SEQ", sequenceName = "GAME_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "GAME_SEQ")
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String gameName;

    @Column(nullable = false , unique=true)
    private String gameCode;

}

     gameRepo.save(new Game("game_name_1","game_code_1")) --> it saves entity in DB with ID value as 1
     gameRepo.save(new Game("game_name_2","game_code_2")) --> it saves entity in DB with ID value as 2
     gameRepo.save(new Game("game_name_3","game_code_2")) --> save failed as 'game_code_2' already exists
     gameRepo.save(new Game("game_name_3","game_code_3")) --> it saves entity in DB with ID value as 4 . 
     **Here I am expecting ID value should be 3 as previous one was not saved**.
```

Could anyone please let me know how to overcome this issue.

Thanks,
Madhu.

Comment: The ID should be meaningless. What does it matter? https://help.heroku.com/PRNW4R5Z/why-are-there-gaps-in-my-postgres-id-sequence

Comment: That's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I am not facing any problems because of this. But, I just want to know why it is behaving like this.. :)

Comment: But your question is on "how to overcome the issue" - the answer to that is: there is nothing to "overcome" or to fix.

Comment: Your sequence is behaving that way because it is designed that way. You are looking at it from the prospective of a single user, but Postgres is a multi user 'application'. Consider 2 users hitting the same table. User 1 creates a row and continues processing the transaction meanwhile user 2 also creates a row and commits. Then for some reason, user 1 rolls back, thus giving up the generated sequence. Should the sequence generated for user 2 now be updated? Now, instead of 2 users there were 2000. Sequences are monotonically increasing counters; once a value is used it's forever gone.